# Cannot open file using fopen (php)

Tags: php, file-io, fopen

I am trying to open a file for reading in php script but having trouble.

This is my code

```
$fileHandle = fopen("1234_main.csv", "r")or die("Unable to open");
if (!file_exists($fileHandle))
{
    echo "Cannot find file.";
}
```

The script is in the same directory as the file I am trying to read and there are no other read/write permission errors as I can create/read other files in the same directory.

When I run the script I just get the "Cannot find file" error message.  Why is this error message being shown?  Surely if fopen() can't open the file the "or die statement" should end the script?

Also, why can't I open the file when it definitely exists and is in the same location as the script (I have also tried using the full path of the filename instead of just the filename).

I am fairly new to php (but have exp in c++) so if its a stupid question I apologize.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_exists()` take the file-name as input, but the logic of your code has problem. You first try to open a file then you check its existence?

You first should check its existence by `file_exists("1234_main.csv")` and if it exists try to open it.

Comment: Yeh my logic is backwards - I think it was that i put the file_exists() in when trying to find out why I couldn't open a file an was trying to find out why.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't open it? if it couldn't you should receive "Unable to open"

Comment: after attempting to open the file. I was testing whether the $fileHandle == null. and that was evaluating to true.

Comment: Try to read it by `$content = fread($fileHandle, filesize($filename));` and `echo $content` to see if you can read it or not.

Comment: @unknownSPY fopen returns FALSE on error, you should check it against FALSE

Comment: Nothing gets outputted.

Comment: Was anything in the file? you can enter some dummy data there, also you may try another file.

Comment: Tried another file and that didn't output anything either

Comment: did you compare the $fileHandle with FALSE?  The file must be accessible to PHP, so you need to ensure that the file access permissions allow this access.

Comment: $fileHandle = true so there I don't think its permissions based.

Comment: Ah Fixed it - although I don't know how... Thanks for the help

Comment: What did you try to read from file, you shouldn't just copy paste the code I gave you, the $filename in filesize must be your file name "1234_main.csv"

Comment: @unknownSPY How did you find it was fixed? by getting content? anyway if my suggestions helpt you don't forget to vote the answer up and probably accpet it as answer.

Comment: Hi - The site unfortunately doesn't allow me to up vote as I don't have enough rep yet. I knew that it was fixed as I started getting content.  probably a syntax error.  Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) expects a file name rather than a handle. Try this:

```
$fileName = "1234_main.csv";
if (!file_exists($fileName))
{
    echo "Cannot find file.";
} else {
    $fileHandle = fopen($fileName, "r")or die("Unable to open");
}
```

Also keep in mind that filenames have to be specified relative to the originally requested php-script when executing scripts on a web server.

Comment: ok - good to know about file_exists()

but it still can't find the file.

Comment: How are you executing the script? For web servers, the filename is relative to the webroot.

Comment: Web server.  Do I need to put a file path in if the script is in the same directory as the file that's being opened?

Comment: That depends whether you request the php file directly or include it from another file. The .csv path has to be provided relatively to the requested .php

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file_get_content()` for this operation. On failure, `file_get_contents()` will return FALSE.For example

```
$file = file_get_contents('1234_main.csv');

if( $file === false ){
    echo "Cannot find file.";   
}
```

Comment: Use `$file === false` in this case! Check the big red hint: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php Also, OP might not want the entire contents.

Comment: Maybe we can use function `file()` for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

`file_exists` takes a string, not a file handle. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php